# Unpack list of tuples to check that middle value in each tuple doesn't exceed a certain amount

Tags: scala, dictionary, tuples

I've been trying unpack each tuple in a list of tuples and check to see that the middle value in each tuple doesn't exceed a certain amount in an equation. I keep getting ") expected but => found." I'm already pushing my knowledge by attempting this, so I have no idea what is wrong?

```
def howmuch(m: Int, n: Int): List[Any] = {
  val a = ((m-1) to (n-1)).toList
  val b = a.map(i =>
    if (((7 / 9.0 * i + 1 / 9.0) % 1) == 0) (7*i+2,i,(7 / 9.0 * i + 1 / 9.0).toInt) else n+1)

  val c = b.map((i._1,i._2,i._3) => if (9*(i._3)+1 <=n) (i._1,i._2,i._3) else n+1)
  c
}
```

Comment: Why not just use an IDE? Intellij Idea is free (the community version), is a decent IDE and supports Scala out of the box. Just paste this code inside it (or your favorite IDE) and it should point you to the problematic area right  away.

Comment: The code is difficult to read,doesn't make sense in some parts and it is not clear what it should do. Care to explain what are you trying to implement?

Comment: The code is trying to return a tuple of 3 numbers for each number between (m-1) to (n-1) that returns a whole number when put into the equation. 7/9.0* 'i'+1/9.0. The values in the tuple are based off of 'i'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first rule of `if`/`else` is that the types of both sides should match.

Let's look at the first one (reformatted to make it easier to read).

```
a.map(i =>
    if (((7 / 9.0 * i + 1 / 9.0) % 1) == 0)
      (7*i+2, i, (7 / 9.0 * i + 1 / 9.0).toInt) //(Int,Int,Int) tuple
    else n+1                                    //Int
  )
```

So if `a` is something like `List(5,6,7)` then the result will be `List(8, (37,5,4), 8)`. This a list of type `List[Any]`. That's a very bad sign. Whenever you encounter type `Any` in Scala code it should raise a red flag.

Next you're trying to `map()` over this list. Not only do you get the syntax all wrong, each element is type `Any`. You can't treat each element as if it were a tuple because it's not a `Tuple`, it's an `Any`. You can't add `1` to an element because it's not an `Int`, it's an `Any`.

Time to  go back and rethink this from the beginning.