# Scala Multi Dimensional Array

Tags: arrays, scala

I have the following two arrays

```scala
val a = Array(1,2)
val b = Array(0,a)
println(b(1)(0)) //'Any' does not take parameters
```

In the above example I can't index the value in the second array as '(0)' is not allowed. The expected result should print the value 1.

Is this possible?

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: b has become an ```Array[Any]``` because you put an int and an array there. So it has become the most common type, which is ```Any```. So when you access it, it returns an ```Any```, so you cannot index.

Comment: [This recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60664988/4993128) touches on the problems with type `Any`. What you want is `val b = Array(Array(0),a)`. That's a proper multi-dimensional `Array`.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Multi-Dimensional Array is an array with more than two dimensions. In a matrix, the two dimensions are represented by rows and columns.

```
val a = Array(1, 2)
val b: Array[Any] = Array(0, a)
println(b(1)(0)) //'Any' does not take parameters. since b is not a valid Multi-Dimensional Array 

val aa = Array(3, 4)
val c: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(aa, a) //Valid Multi-Dimensional Array
println(c(1)(0))
```